# How to use boost when using the keyboard?

Tags: overcooked

I discovered that you could use circle (I'm using PS4 controllers) to boost your character when walking in a direction. However I don't have enough controllers so I also use a keyboard but haven't discovered how to boost using that.

What is the key to boost using the keyboard?

Answer (score 4):

The <kbd>Alt</kbd> key.

Shame how the game doesn't let you customize controls, or at least tell you.